# Pass Date object from javascript to asp.net mvc controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, date

I have a Date variable in client side and I want to pass the Date variable to my controller at server side. 
I have passed as a normal field and the date is defaulting to 01-01-0001 12:00:00 AM.

help me to convert the date field with the right format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC expects the DateTime value to be in the format of Thread.CurrentLanguage. Please check what language you are using.

Its like that because users might enter a Date in a TextBox and the they would enter the format of their language.

Like Pieter said: an easy way is to use a string in this case.

Another way is to use

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
}
```

in Global.Asax.

You can switch back to the language of the user in a filter after the ModelBinding happend:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
     {
             string language = //find a way to get the language - I have it in the route
             Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
             Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
         base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)
     }
```

This way has some risks, but I find it easier in lots of situations if modelBinding uses InvariantCulture (think of decimal values in the route, datetime in the route...)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be the easiest to pass the string representation of the date to the ASP.NET MVC action and attempt to parse it using [DateTime.TryParse(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(string dateTimeString)
{
    DateTime tempDateTime;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out tempDateTime))
    {
       //Handle
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the datetime is a filed of my model and I am using default modelbinder. is there any way to pass the date in correct format from the client?

Comment: Ohh, Check Malcolm Frexner's response :)